# How to put a generic function type into std::map?

Tags: c++, function, templates, stdmap

Can I use a generic function type as the value of std::map? This eliminates the need to write different std::maps for different function parameters and return values.

```
template<class Function,class ... Args>
inline auto FuncWrapper(Function &&f, Args && ... args)-> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

std::map<std::string, FuncWrapper>> FUNCS;

void test_map_operator()
{
    FUNCS["MD5"]([](std::string data){ return "MD5: "+ data; }, "some data");
    FUNCS["RSA"]([](std::string data, std::string key) {return "RSA: "+ data +':' + key;}, "some data", "some key");
    FUNCS["Other"]([](int a, double b, char c){return (c-'0')+a+b;}, 1, 2.0, 'c');
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I don’t believe there’s a way to do this directly because the types of the stored functions would be different. There may be some way to achieve this by adding a layer of indirection, though.

Comment: You can do it, but it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility could be to have a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (but a known one) of [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (or [function objects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)).

So combine [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) with [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

For example, consider having some

```
std::map<std::string, 
       std::variant<std::function(void(int)>, 
                    std::function(double(std::string))>> mapunion;
```

Your tagged union might  contain smart  pointers, e.g. some `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

Using templates you cant achieve this.

Its a different type in C++.

Related to this would be the following:
Take any stl container all of them provide a custom Allocater template, a big problem was that one container that had a different allocater wasnt assignable from the same container that had a different Allocater type.

Btw, because of this Bloomberg bd library rewrote stl containers just using virtual Allocaters which is ok because it uses dynamic dispatch.

Comment: You must be coming from Java. There is no type erasure in C++. Templates are compile type concepts. Unless if you mean void*.

Comment: There is type erasure in C++, e.g. `std::function` erases the type of function objects